# Solving second order nonhomogeneous differential equation with non-constant coefficients using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$ty''(t) + y'(t) -ty(t)= tf(t)$

How to solve the problem using Laplace Transform?

---

Using Laplace transform I got $$Y(s)= C(s^2-a^2)^{-1/2}  + (s^2-a^2)^{-1/2}\int   (s^2-a^2)^{-1/2}F(s)\,ds$$ where $C$ is constant. What is the inverse?

Comment: Using Laplace transform I got Y(s)= (s^2-a^2)^(-1/2)*C + (s^2-a^2)^(-1/2)*\int (s^2-a^2)^(-1/2)*F(s) ds where C is constant.  What is the inverse?

Comment: any idea what  $f$  is?

Comment: f is any function depends of the t

Comment: What on earth is $a$?

Comment: $$
a = 1,
$$    in this case

Comment: suppose  $$f(t) = f(t) \ \ \ \  \hbox{to} \ \ \ \ \  t<T \\  \ \ \ \ \  0 \ \ \ \ \hbox{otherwise} $$